# how can i parse a json file to an array of objects in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a json file i require this file to my json code and i need to parse it in an array of objects 
this for exemple the json file

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "title": "Star Wars",
      "year": 1977,
      "director": "George Lucas"
    },
    {
      "title": "The Empire Strikes Back",
      "year": 1980,
      "director": "Irvin Kershner"
    },
    {
      "title": "Return of the Jedi",
      "year": 1983,
      "director": "Richard Marquand"
    }]
}
```

and i want to convert it to this array

```
[{title:"Star Wars", year:1977, director:"George Lucas"},{},{}]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read out the *movies* property:

```
var parsedJSON = require('./filename.json');
var result = parsedJSON.movies;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file string using `JSON.parse(..)` :

```
const  fs = require('fs');

var fileString = fs.readFileSync('movies.txt').toString();
var fileObj = JSON.parse(fileString);
var moviesArr = fileObj.movies;
console.log(moviesArr);
```